# How to filter an array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssearchfield

I have chosen to populate an NSTableview by using a mutable array of dictionary objects where the dictionary key is the column identifier and the value is the column value. I populate the array like this:

```
var compArray: NSMutableArray = []

let dict = ["idCompany": id, "company": companyName, "compType": 
companyType] as [String : Any]
            compArray.add(dict)
```

id, company and compType come from an SQlite query.

I use compArray as the tableView data source. This works great. There is no array controller involved.

Table is loaded as follows using CDM which is an instance of the class that delivers the compArray

```
//Define the function that will get the data for each cell for each 
//row.
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

    //Define constant dict as an NSDictionary and set to the DM 
    //instance of the DataModel class at the row being loaded into the 
    //table. DM needs to be cast as an NSDictionary. row is passed in as a 
    //parameter by the OS
    let tdict:NSDictionary = CDM.compArray[row] as! NSDictionary

    //Define strKey as the column identifier for the column being 
    //loaded. Column being loaded is passed in as a parameter by the OS
    let strKey = (tableColumn?.identifier)!

    //method will return the value from dict (which is loaded from 
    //CDM.compArray) for the key that is equal to the column identifier 
    //which was loaded to strKey
    return tdict.value(forKey: strKey.rawValue)
}
```

What I would like to do is introduce an NSSearch field to search all the columns of the tableview.

I added the searchfield as an action and I also added code to store compArray into a copy called backupCompArray.

I defined an isSearching variable:

```
//The variable is set to true when searching
var isSearching = false {
    //This will be fired if the state of isSearching changes ie false 
    //to true or true to false
    didSet {

        //Test to see whether isSearching now has a new value and if 
        //so we do the housekeeping
        if isSearching != oldValue {

            //If isSearching is now true then it must have previously 
            //been false and we now need to back up the original array
            if isSearching {
                //Back up the original array
                backUpCompArray = compArray
            } else{
                //It is now turning from true to false so need to 
//restore
                compArray = backUpCompArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to filter compArray based on the .stringValue of the searchfield.

I have put the following in the @IBAction of the searchfield:

```
@IBAction func searchField(_ sender: NSSearchFieldCell) {
    if sender.stringValue.isEmpty {
        //If stringValue is empty then cant be searching and this can 
        //trigger the restore of the original array
        isSearching = false
    } else {

        //If stringValue is not empty then must be searching. When the 
        //search starts need to backup the original array
        isSearching = true

        //?????????????
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I need to replace the ? with code that can set compArray by applying a filter to backupCompArray returning any rows to compArray where the dictionary values for keys "company" and "compType" contains the searchfield.Stringvalue. I can then use the modified compArray to load the table with only filtered rows.

So I tried your code and got two errors that I tried to fix as follows:

```
//Can use the .filter method it will iterate each value in the array
        CDM.compArray = backupCompArray.filter(using: {
            // this is where you determine whether to include the 
specific element, $0
            $0["company"]!.contains(sender.stringValue) &&
            $0["compType"]!.contains(sender.stringValue)
            // or whatever search method you're using instead
        })
    }
```

That is inserting 'using' and changing searchString to sender.Stringvalue.

But I now get: [image]

against the line that ends with &&

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just general advise: don't use `NSMutableArray` but just use a regular array, and use a custom data type instead of a bunch of dictionaries. It will make everything a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it done like that. Thing is this was my first MacOs app and the first tutorial I went through showed it done like I have done it

Comment: I just downloaded Xcode 10 so I think thats 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Swift 4's `Array.filter()`. It takes a function where you can do your computation. You actually shouldn't need to back up your compArray, unless you need to keep it around later for something else.

```
compArray = compArray.filter({
    // this is where you determine whether to include the specific element, $0
    $0["company"]!.contains(searchString) &&
    $0["compType"]!.contains(searchString)
    // or whatever search method you're using instead
})
```

Comment: SO I tried your answer and got two errors that I tried to fix in the in the code at the end of the original question but I still get an error that I dont understand where I am going wrong

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? I don't need to use `using:` on my end.

Comment: Shouldn't need to use `using:` then. Why are you using an NSMutableArray rather than a normal Swift array? They should be bridged so you can still pass it to Obj-C code just fine.

Comment: I don't know if NSMutableArray supports `filter()` like the Swift array has. (It may take an Obj-C block instead.)

Comment: My app makes use of structs to pass data around in other situations. Would it be better to return an array of companyStructs, use an array controller and use bindings to bind the array controller to the tableview columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181095/discussion-between-silverwolf-and-colin-w).